# C++ Keeping a reference /pointer of an abstract type

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and this question probably seems noobish as I'm just more of a Java/Actionscript3 and I've never dealt with memory related things before.

Anyhow as for the problem I have:
Scene is an abstract class (so I can derive from it and have multiple scenes, like MainScene etc')

What I wanted SceneManager to do is have a pointer / reference to the selected scene (curSc)
And then I'd set the scene like so: setScene(&someScene)

But as I understand, to have a pointer I must also initialize it like so:
curSc = new Scene;
But it won't let me do that as Scene is an abstract class..

```
class Scene {

public:
    Scene(void){}
    virtual ~Scene(void){}
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void render() = 0;
};


class SceneManager {

public:
    SceneManager(void);
    ~SceneManager(void);
    void setScene(Scene *sc);
    Scene* curSc;
}
```

So far it seems to me like using a pointer in this case is wrong and it won't work..
But I'd love to know how to achieve the functionality I'm trying to obtain here

Thank you very much

**Edit by request:**
that's how I tried to use it:

Firstly I have a derived class named GameScene and here it is:

```
class GameScene : public Scene 
{
public:
    GameScene(void);
    void render();
    void update();
}
```

in my main() function I have:

```
GameScene gamescene;
ScreenManager manager;

manager.setScene(&gamescene);
```

Comment: `setScene(&someScene)` will most probably lead to a bug! You take the address of `someScene`, which means that `someScene` is not a pointer. Now the question is: Where does `someScene` live? If it is a local variable, then it will be destroyed as soon as you leave the scope where it is declared, and the pointer stored in `SceneManager` will point to an object that no longer exists. Rule of thumb: Do not use the address-of operator (&something) unless you know *exactly* what you are doing. Don't use pointers, either, but read about smart pointers and use those!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. You can not do

```
curSc = new Scene
```

because it is abstract. If you actually want to declare an instance of `Scene` then make it non abstract. i.e. implement all the methods.

**OR** (I think this is what you intended to do) create a class that inherits from `Scene` and implements all the virtual methods.

```
class View : public Scene {

public:
   View(){}
   virtual ~View(void){}
   virtual void update();
   virtual void render();
};
```

and implement the virtual methods like

```
void View::update() {
//
}

void View::render() {
//
}
```

Then you can implement setScene as

```
void SceneManager::setScene(Scene *sc)
{
  curSc = sc;
}
```

and call it like

```
SceneManager smag;
Scene *nsc = new View;
smag.setScene(nsc);
```

Comment: I already did so, but how do I pass that class correctly to the setScene method? And won't I need to initialize the pointer by the way?

Comment: I passed it into the setScene and did curSc = sc; but then when I tried to use curSc it gave me access violation errors, which I thought I got because I didn't initialize the pointer before, but then again I don't want to initialize the pointer to a derived class, as I might set the scene to many different kinds

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use it? add an edit to the question if you need space.

Comment: Soory I missed SceneManager on the definition of setScene. I have fixed it.

Comment: The code works fine except the fact that you have not defined the constructors and destrutors for `SceneManager`. You have declared them but have not defined them.

Comment: See here. http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ZrNvL$9 . I have removed the ctor and dtor. And made the curSc public just for a demo.

Comment: I just commented on JohnB's answer about that too, it seems like your solutions only will take one class that derived from Scene, yet I want to keep the option to use many classes that derived from Scene, rather than just View

Comment: You can pass any class that inherits from Scene  :). And has implemented all the pure virtual function.s

Comment: Are you certain that this is a proper code? afaik you must initialize the pointer o-o

Comment: Afaik I needed to initialize curSc, but I didn't do so because I'd have to do something like curSc = new View; and then it'd limit me only to View ( i might use other scenes that derived from Scene during runtime) so I didn't initialize it and I encountered problems

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27282/discussion-between-stardust-and-don)

Answer (score 1):

you need a concrete derived class of Scene:

```
class MyScene: public Scene {

public:
   MyScene(void){}
   virtual ~MyScene(void){}
   virtual void update();
   virtual void render();
};
```

And void setScene(Scene *sc) will be:

```
void setScene(Scene *sc)
{
  curSc = (Scene*)sc;
}
```

sc will be MyScene pointer in this case. Abstract class instances (ie interfaces) can not be created and Scene is just an interface here.

Comment: Did you mean curSc = sc; ?

Comment: What about initializing the pointer though? I tried to do it before like that and I didn't initialize it, I got access violation errors afterwards

Comment: See my comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong to use pointer here. But unlike a reference, a pointer urges its user to account for `NULL`. That is the caveat. Reference can refer to `NULL` as well, but adding defense against it will lead you to the ["dark side"](http://www.gotw.ca/conv/002.htm). So, it is reasonable to assume reference will refer to alive object and in this sense references are better than pointers.

Now, if you really-really want to keep the reference you can use in-place construction technique, because you can (re)assign reference by constructor:

```
class SceneManager {

public:
    SceneManager(Scene& sc) : curSc(sc) {}
    ~SceneManager(void);
    SceneManager& setScene(Scene &sc) {
        SceneManager* cheatCompiler = new(this) SceneManager(sc);
        return *cheatCompiler;
    }
    Scene& curSc; 
}
```

Note, that this is kind of quirky stuff. Since compilers try to outsmart us all the time, I can not guarantee it will work in all cases.

That said I would still recommend you using the pointer. If you dont want to check for NULL all the time, you can implement something like [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You should use smart pointers, and do not make member variables public. Example:

```
class Scene {
public:
    virtual ~Scene(){}
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void render() = 0;
};

class MyScene : public Scene {
public:
    virtual void update () { /*...*/ }
    virtual void render () { /*...*/ }
};

class SceneManager {

public:
    SceneManager();
    ~SceneManager();
    void setScene(const std::shared_ptr<Scene> & sc) {
       curSc = sc;
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Scene> curSc;
};

void someProc () {
    std::shared_ptr<Scene> sc = std::make_shared<MyScene> ();  
    auto manager = std::make_shared<SceneManager> ();
    manager->setScene (sc);
    // ...
}
```

Without smart pointers, this would look like (but remember to `delete` the objects created with `new` if they are not needed anymore):

```
class Scene {
public:
    virtual ~Scene(){}
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void render() = 0;
};

class MyScene : public Scene {
public:
    virtual void update () { /*...*/ }
    virtual void render () { /*...*/ }
};

class SceneManager {

public:
    SceneManager();
    ~SceneManager();
    void setScene(Scene * sc) {
       curSc = sc;
    }
private:
    Scene * curSc;
};

void someProc () {
    Scene * sc = new MyScene;
    SceneManager * manager = new SceneManager;
    manager->setScene (sc);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the great informative answer, but the thing is that I didn't want to limit myself to only one class that derives from scene, you initialized the pointer like so: Scene * sc = new MyScene; but what if I have 10 types of scenes that I might decide to set them instead?

Comment: Declare the other classes (e.g. `MySecondScene`) and replace `new MyScene` by `new MySecondScene`

Comment: Yeah.. I was trying to avoid that ;/ I wanted to have an option to change it to many types of scenes during runtime rather than changing the code for that

Comment: ??? You need not change `SceneManager` at all in order to handle other types of scenes. Don't confuse different classes with different objects of the same class! You can create as many MyScene's as you like.